# Rspec fill_in update giving errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I've been at this for 2 days and i've exhausted all questions. So hopefully, SO can help out.

I have the following code in my user_pages_spec.rb

```
describe "edit" do
  let(:org_person) {FactoryGirl.create(:org_person)}
  let(:org_credential) { FactoryGirl.create(:org_credential, :org_person_id => org_person.id ) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:org_contact) }
  before do
    session_sign_in org_credential
    visit edit_org_person_path(org_credential.org_person_id)
  end

  describe "page" do
    it { should have_content('Update your profile') }
    it { should have_title('Edit user') }
    it { should have_css('ul.nav-sidebar', count:3 )}
  end

  describe "with valid information" do

    let(:address1)  { "1234 Fake Street" }
    let(:address2)  { "Unit 95B" }
    let(:new_city) { "Toronto" }
    let(:new_country) { "124" } #country is an id of the corresponding record
    let(:new_region) { "527" } #region is an id of the corresponding record
    let(:new_postal) { "T4M 5R4" }
    let(:new_email) { "donny@example.com" }
    let(:new_business_number) { "60445612344" }
    let(:new_cell_number) { "7451354545" }

    before do
      fill_in "Address 1",            with: address1
      fill_in "Address 2",            with: address2
      fill_in "City",                 with: new_city
      have_select('Country', :selected => :new_country)
      have_select('Region', :selected => :new_region)
      fill_in "Postal Code",               with: new_postal
      fill_in "Email",                with: new_email
      fill_in "Business Number",      with: new_business_number
      fill_in "Cell Number",          with: new_cell_number
      click_button "Save Changes"
    end

    it { should have_title("Edit user") }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    specify { expect(user.reload.address1).to  eq address1 }
    specify { expect(user.reload.address2).to eq address2 }
    specify { expect(user.reload.city).to  eq new_city }
    specify { expect(user.reload.typ_country_id).to  eq new_country }
    specify { expect(user.reload.typ_region_id).to  eq new_region }
    specify { expect(user.reload.postal_code).to  eq new_postal }
    specify { expect(user.reload.email).to  eq new_email }
    specify { expect(user.reload.business_number).to  eq new_business_number }
    specify { expect(user.reload.cell_number).to  eq new_cell_number }
  end
```

The following is my edit & update function in org_people_controller.rb

```
 def edit
   @person = OrgPerson.find(params[:id])
   @contactInfo = OrgContact.find_or_create_by(org_person_id: params[:id]).attributes
   @person.org_contacts.build(@contactInfo)
 end

 def update
   # Create org_ca to sanitize our hash to proper "contacts" attributes
   @org_ca = update_person_params["org_contacts_attributes"]["0"]
   @org_ca[:typ_country_id] = @org_ca.delete :typ_countries
   @org_ca[:typ_country_id] = @org_ca[:typ_country_id][:id]
   @org_ca[:typ_region_id] = @org_ca.delete :typ_regions
   @org_ca[:typ_region_id] = @org_ca[:typ_region_id][:id]

   # Edit function variables, in case of failed validations and we re-render :edit
   @person = OrgPerson.find_by(id: @org_ca["org_person_id"])
   @contactInfo = OrgContact.find_or_create_by(org_person_id:      @org_ca["org_person_id"]).attributes
   @person.org_contacts.build(@contactInfo)

   # Find contacts and credentials record or create them if necessary
   @contact = OrgContact.find_or_initialize_by(org_person_id: @org_ca["org_person_id"])
   @credential = OrgCredential.find_or_initialize_by(org_person_id: @org_ca["org_person_id"])

   # Try to save it, if it saves, then redirect to the edit page with success
   if @contact.update_attributes(@org_ca) &&  @credential.update_attribute(:user_name, @org_ca["email"])
     flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
     redirect_to edit_org_person_path(current_user)
   else # Failed. Re-render the page as unsucessful
     render :edit
   end
 end
```

My factory:

```
factory :org_contact, :class => 'OrgContact' do |f|
   f.address1 "1324 Fake St"
   f.address2 "Unit 96B"
   f.city "Vancouver"
   f.typ_country_id "Canada" #country is an id of the corresponding record
   f.typ_region_id "British Columbia" #region is an id of the corresponding record
   f.postal_code "V5T 6C7"
   f.email "donn@example.com"
   f.business_number "1234433456"
   f.cell_number "1841355567"
end
```

The error i've been getting are "not equal" when they should be equal errors. That is,

```
Failure/Error: specify { expect(user.reload.city).to  eq new_city }
   expected: "Toronto"
        got: "Vancouver"

   (compared using ==)
```

The form manually works on the webapp. That is if I update the fields, they get changed in the database and all. However, it is just not working in the tests. I have a feeling that the update might not be working, but i am not quite sure how to debug it (still new with TDD and rails and rspec).

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are going to the edit_org_person_path with the id of the org_person, not the user.  So yes, in this case it is possible that the update works, but you are testing with the wrong model.

At first glance, it appears that you are passing the first two 'address' tests.  However, the address in your factory is the same as the address you fill the fields with, which in turn, are the same that you test against.

Some ideas:

Change your factory to use sequences:

```
factory :user do
  sequence( :email ){ |n| "user_#{n}@example.com" }
end
```

Models that come out of that factory will have a new email every time.

You can use your factory to create attributes:

```
let( :attributes ){ FactoryGirl.attributes_for( :org_contact) }
```

Which will allow:

```
fill_in "Address 1", with: attributes[ :address1 ]
```

You may also be interested in 'pry-rails': 
https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails

Once in your gemfile ( and remember to bundle ), you can do something like:

```
it 'lets me bind' do
  binding.pry
end
```

That will pause the test and basically put you in an irb with the current environment.

binding.pry is very useful.  You can put it anywhere in your application.  Just remember not to leave it in your app.

For example, I often find myself placing it the 'create' action of a controller:

```
def create
  @thing = Thing.new( thing_params )
  binding.pry
end
```

When the application reaches that code, I can type commands:

```
> @thing.valid?
false            ## hmmm
> @thing.errors
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, org_person_id is a FK of org_credential and org_contact that points to org_person. It is used in the edit function to find the person in our database if the record exists and to find_or_create their contact information if needed. 

Thank you for the pry-rails. Didn't know that existed. Pretty nifty gem!